# Container-type: inline-size collapsing on some IOS displays

Tags: css, ios

This script works on my dekstop/laptop but fails when browsing on my phone (iPhone 13 with IOS 17.1 using Chrome version 119). Testing on another phone it worked fine but this was an older phone?!?

Testing on browserstack.com shows the same error.

Below is a simplified example in codepen with this error but below is my real CSS. It's hard to debug a phone but from what I can see the contents of my product div is collapsing, when I remove overflow hidden is shows some content.

I've spent days on this but seem to be making no progress.

https://codepen.io/kodee/pen/OJdpezJ

````
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.grid{
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 2.2rem;
  width:100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(220px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:  200px 100px auto;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.product{
    display: grid;
    grid-row: span 3;
    grid-template-rows: subgrid;
    gap:1rem;
    background: var(--test);
    color: var(--black);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    width: 100%;

}```
````